# SQL Query to get highest values based on one column by grouping on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am running the following SQL query to select the highest priced product in each product category in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp

```
SELECT  p.ProductID, p.productName, p.Price, p.CategoryID, c.CategoryName
FROM [Categories] c
LEFT JOIN [Products] p
ON (c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID)
WHERE Price IN (SELECT Max(Price) FROM Products GROUP BY CategoryID)
ORDER BY p.CategoryID
```

However, the output that is generated is giving 2 results for some categories like category 3 and 4. Why is that happening? and how can I modify the code to get only highest result for each? Also, how do I get lowest for each category?

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
   slect a.* from (SELECT  p.ProductID, p.productName, p.Price, p.CategoryID, c.CategoryName,
      row_number()over(partition by p.CategoryID order by p.Price desc) rn
    FROM [Categories] c
    LEFT JOIN [Products] p
    ON c.CategoryID = p.CategoryID
    ) a where a.rn=1
```

Answer (score 1):

`APPLY` comes to mind as perhaps the simplest approach:

```
SELECT p.ProductID, p.productName, p.Price, p.CategoryID, c.CategoryName
FROM categories c OUTER APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) p.*
      FROM Products p
      WHERE p.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
      ORDER BY p.Price DESC
     ) p
ORDER BY c.CategoryID
```